# How to run headless Firefox on Xvfb

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, centos, gecko

I am trying to run a webdriver with geckodriver. I have installed selenium gecko, firefox and have python27. My folder has the script and the geckodriver.

When am running from centOS the command python script.py it says

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to start browser: permission denied
```

Below is the script I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/local/firefox')
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

before you ask, when I run `whereis firefox` I get `firefox: /usr/local/bin/firefox /usr/local/firefox`

**Edit:**

After I ran `sudo yum -y install firefox Xvfb libXfont Xorg` the python scipt launched but I got an error on the geckdriverlog saying:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/local/firefox/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I think this is due to [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1372998) bug. Therefore I tried `sudo yum install libdbus-glib-1-2` but it said, `No package libdbus-glib-1-2 available.`

**Edit 2:**

So perhaps I should ask (which might be the answer to the question);
How can I ge the lib from [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/36561683/dir/centos_6/com/dbus-glib-0.86-6.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) with my terminal install `libdbus-glib-1-2` on CentOS?

**Edit 3:**

So basically to run the headless firefox I need Xvfb but when I run it `Xvfb :19 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &` I get stuck on `Initializing built-in extension GLX` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012667/xvfb-freezes-initializing-glx-extension) question. So I think the problem boils down to how to run headless Firefox on Xvfb.

Lastly I just have to add, the thing with the Firefox versions is just a mess.

Comment: are you on mac?

Comment: No am on CentOS

Comment: the error is only when you run headless ? or the error is coming in headful too.

Comment: I cant run headful as its just an aws server.

Comment: I honestly dont know what to do with the bounty since it ends in 13h and I still haven't gotten a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found other people have same issue, though you tried `which`, Can you check `/usr/local/bin/firefox/firefox` workable?

Comment: I tried (since I updated a few things, check the question again, it says the error in the edit now)

Comment: What about browser = webdriver.Firefox() instead of any profile.

Comment: Thats not the issue anymore, cause when I write `firefox` on my terminal I get that `libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Couldn't load XPCOM.` So I think thats they issue now.